# Integration problems

Tags: calculus, integration

Due to a high demand for tablets , a tablet manufacturer increased its rate of production worldwide according to the logistic function

$$N'(t) = \frac{83e^{1.97t}}{22+e^{1.97t}}$$ thousand tablets per year

where t is measured in years with $ t = 0$ corresponding to January

2012, and $N(0) =0 $

Find an expression for the total number of tablets manufactured at any time, $t$ .

From my understanding ,

When t=0, total number of tablet produced is 0

I need to integrate $N'(t)$ to find the total no. Of tablets .

$\int (83e^{1.97t})(22+e^{1.97t})^{-1}$

Let u = $22+e^{1.97t}$

$dt = \frac{1}{1.97e^{1.97}} du $

$\int (83e^{1.97t})(u)^{-1} \frac{1}{1.97e^{1.97t}} du $

$ = \frac {8300}{197(22+e^{1.97t)} } + C $

As the question states 'Any time' I know that I have to do something with C. 
However , I got more confused and got stuck

Any help will be appreciated!

The answer is 
$N(t) = 42.1 \ln (22+e^{1.97t}) - 132 $

Comment: You know that N(0) = 0 , use that information to solve for C

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$N(T)-N(0)=\int_0^T\frac{83e^{1.97t}}{22+e^{1.97t}}dt=\frac{83}{1.97}[\ln(22+e^{1.97T})-\ln 23].$$ Since $N(0)=0$ it follows that

$$N(t)=\frac{83}{1.97}[\ln(22+e^{1.97t})-\ln 23].$$

Comment: I'm not sure what to do after I integrate $N'(t)$

Comment: The limits of the integration are given by T and 0, where T is used for the "any time" stated in the question, because the integral with these limits gives the total number of tablets produced between time t=o and t=T.

Answer (score 0):

You have
$\int (83e^{1.97t})(22+e^{1.97t})^{-1}$

and you substituted $e^{1.97 t}+22=u$

$t=\dfrac{\log (u-22)}{1.97}$

$dt=\dfrac{du}{1.97 (u-22)}$

and the integral becomes

$$\int \dfrac{42.132}{u} \, du=42.132 \log u +C=42.132 \log \left(e^{1.97 t}+22\right)+C$$

as $N(0)=0$ plug $t=0$ in the previous result to get

$42.132 \log \left(e^{1.97 \cdot 0}+22\right)+C=0$

$C=-42.132 \log \left(1+22\right)=-132.1$

Thus the function is $N(t)=42.132 \log \left(e^{1.97 t}+22\right)-132.1$

Hope this helps